# Getting checkboxList values as per selected category from parent checkboxList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to fetch checkboxlist from database (working). There is two checkboxlist on page: first gets fetch when page loads, second gets fetched selected values from first checkboxList. That is also working when I select first time from first checkboxList. But when I select second value from first checkboxList then string gets structured like this

> ('Value1','Value2 " & vbLf & "')

It should make string like this

> ('Value1','value2')

Now I don't understand what is this `& vbLf &`.

```
Dim joiner As String = ""
Dim whereClause As String = String.Empty
Dim categoryCondition As String = String.Empty

For i = 0 To categoryFilter.Items.Count - 1
    If categoryFilter.Items(i).Selected Then
        Dim category As String = categoryFilter.Items(i).ToString
        categoryCondition = String.Concat(categoryCondition, joiner, String.Format("'{0}'", category))
        If joiner = "" Then joiner = ","
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Are you sure that linefeed character is being generated in the code you've shown above?

Comment: You are trying to join items together in a very complicated way. Look into [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @AndrewMortimer you were right there was a problem in my table data row because I pasted them from excel and there was some blank space line in some rows..

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in functionality to get the checked items and concatenate the string with LINQ

1. Get the checked items from the control (`categoryFilter.CheckedItems`)
2. Convert them to String (`Cast(Of String)()`)
3. Put `'` around them individually (`Select()`)
4. Join them together with `,` (`Aggregate()`)

Code:

```
Dim categoryCondition As String = Me.categoryFilter.CheckedItems.
    Cast(Of String)().
    Select(Function(i1) String.Format("'{0}'", i1)).
    Aggregate(Function(i1, i2) String.Format("{0}, {1}", i1, i2))
```

If the line feed still exists, it's probable that it exists in the `CheckedListBox` items itself. You said that's coming from your database, so maybe that's (not working).